# Why can I not set the volume of an AxWindowsMediaPlayer object with a slider?

Tags: vb.net, axwindowsmediaplayer

Whenever I try to say the volume of the media player like this:

```
Private Sub SndMasterSlider_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SndMasterSlider.ValueChanged
    Player1.settings.volume = SndMasterSlider.Value
End Sub
```

I get this error: `An exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException' occurred in AxInterop.WMPLib.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: how are you instantiating the OCX control? also, min and max volumes for WMP are 0 to 100 i believe.

Comment: short answer: Use the Scroll event instead of ValueChanged

Comment: @porkchop I'm not. I'm guessing that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the Slider is the `TrackBar` control, you will get that exception when creating the form (you did not say where, but I'll bet that is where).  This is because the Designer code will set the `Value` thus firing the ValueChanged event before it has created your `AxWMP` control:

```
 Me.TrackBar1.Value = 50
```

This will fire the event even though the form is being created.  You can set a flag to indicate when to process the `ValueChanged` event, manually add the handler or just use the `Scroll` event which will fire when the user actually moves the thumb.

```
Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(...
    AxWMP.settings.volume = TrackBar1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: The scroll event does not work for some reason. Whenever I scroll the trackbar, nothing happens. (It's a `gTrackBar`, not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: gTrackBar sounds like a variable name. The standard MS/NET TrackBar uses the Scroll event as the default event (click on the control and it opens that event), if yours opens to ValueChanged, it might be a different control. The other alternative is to use a flag that starts as False, set it to true at the end of Form Load; then at the top of the ValueChanged event add: `If _FormLoadedFlag = False Then Exit Sub`.  this will prevent it from trying to set the volume before the AxWMp control has been created.